# How to embed basic HTML page using Qt?

Tags: python, html, python-2.7, pyside2, qwebengineview

I am using PySide2.QtWebEngineWidgets.QWebEngineView() to setHtml on it to show a basic page like below.

This html file works fine in a browser because it has all the files in the same folder relative to the html file.

Once I setHtml to the below file, I get this exception:

Qt Error:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined
```

Is this related to Qt not finding the relative files unlike a regular browser? Or is there something else I should be doing? Or is QWebEngineView not advanced enough to execute javascript? If so what should I use?

I just want to create a webpage widget and load my Html like below. Everything else is done by the Html code.

To reproduce:

1. Save the below html code as an html file
2. Run this code:

```
from PySide2 import QtCore, QtWidgets, QtGui
from PySide2.QtWebEngineWidgets import QWebEngineView

editor = QWebEngineView()
htmlfile = 'C:/myHtmlFile.html'
with open(htmlfile, 'r') as f:
    html = f.read()
    editor.setHtml(html)
    
editor.show()
```

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8" >
</head>
<body>

<div id="container" style="width:800px;height:600px;border:1px solid grey"></div>

<script src="monaco-editor/min/vs/loader.js"></script>
<script>
    require.config({ paths: { 'vs': 'monaco-editor/min/vs' }});
    require(['vs/editor/editor.main'], function() {
        var editor = monaco.editor.create(document.getElementById('container'), {
            value: [
                'function x() {',
                '\tconsole.log("Hello world!");',
                '}'
            ].join('\n'),
            language: 'javascript',
            fontFamily:"Verdana",
            theme: "vs-dark"
        });
    });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<sub>(disclaimer: I'm not an expert in javascript)</sub>

The require command needs file system information so you can't use an HTML string but you need to create an HTML file and load it using load():

```py
import os

from PySide2 import QtCore, QtWidgets, QtWebEngineWidgets


CURRENT_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys

    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    view = QtWebEngineWidgets.QWebEngineView()

    filename = os.path.join(CURRENT_DIR, "index.html")
    view.load(QtCore.QUrl.fromLocalFile(filename))
    view.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

```
├── index.html
├── main.py
└── monaco-editor
    ├── CHANGELOG.md
    ├── dev
    ├── esm
    ├── LICENSE
    ├── min
    ├── min-maps
    ├── monaco.d.ts
    ├── package.json
    ├── README.md
    └── ThirdPartyNotices.txt
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot it works! I added simplified code just before you replied but it works great now.