# How to get and set the value of monaco editor in Python Qt?

Tags: python, python-2.7, pyside2, monaco-editor, qwebengineview

I am using an instance of the monaco editor in Python Qt (Pyside2) using QWebEngineView similar to how it's shown here:
[How to embed basic HTML page using Qt?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64164738/how-to-embed-basic-html-page-using-qt)

I can edit the code just like in monaco editor. But how can I call functions to get and set the current value of the editor?

I only saw React examples but not Python, so not sure how to do the same thing in Python.

Is this possible to do using Python Qt (Pyside2)?

EDIT: Found this link that shows how to do it for Pyside2:
https://www.itdaan.com/tw/66b0f712b22ff6e617b7b493f7c3c841

Although trying this I get no name called monaco. I will try to simplify the code.

Comment: you could indicate the example(link) in react to be able to implement a similar logic with python

Comment: I couldn't find the react link again but I added the Pyside2 version but I guess I have to do the same workaround you showed in the other thread.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case it is to use QtWebChannel to exchange information between python and javascript as I show below:

**main.py**

```py
import json
import os

from PySide2 import QtCore, QtWidgets, QtWebEngineWidgets, QtWebChannel


CURRENT_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))


class BaseBridge(QtCore.QObject):
    initialized = QtCore.Signal()
    sendDataChanged = QtCore.Signal(str, str)

    def send_to_js(self, name, value):
        data = json.dumps(value)
        self.sendDataChanged.emit(name, data)

    @QtCore.Slot(str, str)
    def receive_from_js(self, name, value):
        data = json.loads(value)
        self.setProperty(name, data)

    @QtCore.Slot()
    def init(self):
        self.initialized.emit()


class EditorBridge(BaseBridge):
    valueChanged = QtCore.Signal()
    languageChanged = QtCore.Signal()
    themeChanged = QtCore.Signal()

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(EditorBridge, self).__init__(parent)
        self._value = ""
        self._language = ""
        self._theme = ""

    def getValue(self):
        return self._value

    def setValue(self, value):
        self._value = value
        self.valueChanged.emit()

    def getLanguage(self):
        return self._language

    def setLanguage(self, language):
        self._language = language
        self.languageChanged.emit()

    def getTheme(self):
        return self._theme

    def setTheme(self, theme):
        self._theme = theme
        self.themeChanged.emit()

    value = QtCore.Property(str, fget=getValue, fset=setValue, notify=valueChanged)
    language = QtCore.Property(
        str, fget=getLanguage, fset=setLanguage, notify=languageChanged
    )
    theme = QtCore.Property(str, fget=getTheme, fset=setTheme, notify=themeChanged)


class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__(parent)

        self._view = QtWebEngineWidgets.QWebEngineView()

        channel = QtWebChannel.QWebChannel(self)
        self.view.page().setWebChannel(channel)

        self._bridge = EditorBridge()
        channel.registerObject("bridge", self.bridge)

        self.setCentralWidget(self.view)

        filename = os.path.join(CURRENT_DIR, "index.html")
        self.view.load(QtCore.QUrl.fromLocalFile(filename))

        self.bridge.initialized.connect(self.handle_initialized)
        self.bridge.valueChanged.connect(self.handle_valueChanged)
        self.bridge.languageChanged.connect(self.handle_languageChanged)
        self.bridge.themeChanged.connect(self.handle_themeChanged)

    @property
    def view(self):
        return self._view

    @property
    def bridge(self):
        return self._bridge

    def handle_initialized(self):
        print("init")
        code = "\n".join(["function x() {", '\tconsole.log("Hello world!");', "}"])
        # Do not use self.bridge.value = code or self.bridge.setValue(code)
        self.bridge.send_to_js("value", code)
        self.bridge.send_to_js("language", "javascript")
        self.bridge.send_to_js("theme", "vs-dark")

    def handle_valueChanged(self):
        print("value:", self.bridge.value)

    def handle_languageChanged(self):
        print("language:", self.bridge.language)

    def handle_themeChanged(self):
        print("theme", self.bridge.theme)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys

    sys.argv.append("--remote-debugging-port=8000")

    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)

    w = MainWindow()
    w.show()

    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

**index.js**

```js
var bridge = null;
var editor = null;

require.config({ paths: { 'vs': 'monaco-editor/min/vs' } });
require(['vs/editor/editor.main'], function () {
    editor = monaco.editor.create(document.getElementById('container'), {
        fontFamily: "Verdana",
    });
    editor.onDidChangeModelContent((event) => {
        sendToPython("value", editor.getModel().getValue())
    })
    editor.onDidChangeModelLanguage((event) => {
        sendToPython("language", event.newLanguage)
    })
});

function init() {
    sendToPython("value", editor.getModel().getValue());
    sendToPython("language", editor.getModel()._languageIdentifier.language);
    sendToPython("theme", editor._themeService._theme.themeName);
}

function sendToPython(name, value) {
    bridge.receive_from_js(name, JSON.stringify(value));
}

function updateFromPython(name, value) {
    var data = JSON.parse(value)
    switch (name) {
        case "value":
            editor.getModel().setValue(data);
            break;
        case "language":
            monaco.editor.setModelLanguage(editor.getModel(), data);
            break;
        case "theme":
            monaco.editor.setTheme(data);
            sendToPython("theme", editor._themeService._theme.themeName);
            break;
    }
}

window.onload = function () {
    new QWebChannel(qt.webChannelTransport, function (channel) {
        bridge = channel.objects.bridge;
        bridge.sendDataChanged.connect(updateFromPython);
        bridge.init();
        init();
    });
}
```

**index.html**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8" >
</head>
<body>

<div id="container" style="width:800px;height:600px;border:1px solid grey"></div>

<script src="monaco-editor/min/vs/loader.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="qrc:///qtwebchannel/qwebchannel.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="index.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

```
├── index.html
├── index.js
├── main.py
└── monaco-editor
    ├── CHANGELOG.md
    ├── dev
    ├── esm
    ├── LICENSE
    ├── min
    ├── min-maps
    ├── monaco.d.ts
    ├── package.json
    ├── README.md
    └── ThirdPartyNotices.txt
```

Comment: Thanks it seems to work. I get this error also: Qt Error: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '_languageIdentifier' of undefined.

Comment: Thanks the error is gone. But when I do: w.bridge.setValue("hello") after w.show(), nothing happens. Is this normal?

Comment: @JoanVenge Note: You should not use setValue (nor any of the setters) since this is used to transmit the information from js, you have to use `send_to_js("value", "text")` but you should do that after the initialized signal is emitted since the bridge works after the connection is made. I emphasize: read the docs of QtWebChannel so that you understand the logic of that module.

Comment: Thanks that makes sense, but when I call w.bridge.send_to_js("value", "text") after w.show(), it's still the same result. Is the signal not emitted after w.show()?

Comment: @JoanVenge mmm, self.show() only invokes that the window is shown and nothing else, but that does not imply that the communication implemented through QtWebChannel was executed so sending a value does not make sense. Given the above, I implemented the "initialized" signal that indicates that the connection was established and information can only be exchanged at that moment, you must understand that Qt is asynchronous.

Comment: Thanks that makes sense. Lastly do you know if it's possible to convert the mainwindow into a normal widget? Because I am hosting this as a widget, main window doesn't show up in the actual host window. I changed class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow): to class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QWidget): but doesn't show anything.

Comment: @JoanVenge That is trivial so you should only change `self.setCentralWidget(self.view)` to `lay = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self) lay.addWidget(self.view)`